# after second ajax call jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting a partial via ajax in asp.net mvc, it work fine for first time and second time but after that, it redirect to page instad of getting page via ajax.

this is my partial page code :

```
<script>

    var jqgd = jQuery.noConflict();
    jqgd(function () {
        jqgd('#getdata-@ViewBag.term').on('click', 'a', function () {
            if (this.href == "") { return; }
            jqgd.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    jqgd('#retrieve-@ViewBag.term').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'> // Added
    jQuery(function ($) {

        $("div, p, a, b, strong, bold, font, span, td")
        .filter(function () {
            return $(this).children(":not(.word)").length == 0
        })
        .each(function () {
            this.innerHTML = $(this).text().replace(/\S+/g, function (word) {
                return "<span class='word'>" + word + "</span>";
            });

            $(".word", this).filter(isEnglish).addClass('english');
            $(".word", this).filter(isPersian).addClass('persian');
        });

        function isEnglish() {
            return $(this).text().charCodeAt(0) < 255;
        }

        function isPersian() {
            return $(this).text().charCodeAt(0) > 255;
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="retrieve-@ViewBag.term">
    <div style="float:right;">
        <div class="searchtitles" style="float: right;">@ViewBag.term</div>
        <table class="jjt" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="j2t">
                <td class="j13t">field</td>
                <td class="j13t">field</td>
                <td class="j13t">field</td>
                <td class="j13t">field</td>
                <td class="j13t">field</td>
                <td class="j13t">field</td>
                <td class="j13t">field</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Terms)
            {
                Mydata 
            }


        </table>

        <div id="getdata-@ViewBag.term" style="float:left; direction:ltr; margin-left:-20px; margin-top:-15px;">@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.Tours, page => Url.Action("results", new { page }))</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i'm using pagedlist and when i change page after second time it seems all jquery commends terminated, what is problem?
can anyone help me ?

**EDIT** : this part of code doesn't work too after second call.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> // Added
        jQuery(function ($) {

            $("div, p, a, b, strong, bold, font, span, td")
            .filter(function () {
                return $(this).children(":not(.word)").length == 0
            })
            .each(function () {
                this.innerHTML = $(this).text().replace(/\S+/g, function (word) {
                    return "<span class='word'>" + word + "</span>";
                });

                $(".word", this).filter(isEnglish).addClass('english');
                $(".word", this).filter(isPersian).addClass('persian');
            });

            function isEnglish() {
                return $(this).text().charCodeAt(0) < 255;
            }

            function isPersian() {
                return $(this).text().charCodeAt(0) > 255;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: did you try `live('click')` instead of `on`

Comment: @madhushankarox : it's not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#getdata-@ViewBag.term` is within the `#retrieve-@ViewBag.term` element but that gets replaced after the first call. You need to use event delegation.

Try this instead:

```
jqgd('#retrieve-@ViewBag.term').on('click', '#getdata-@ViewBag.term a', function () {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have a part of jquery code in my page, in doesnt work too. i copy it to my question, please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You should create a new question instead of editing this one. There you can explain what that code is supposed to do. Also, it is more likely to be seen by others and keep the scope for your questions focused.

Comment: I create a new question, please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218663/after-second-ajax-call-all-jquery-codes-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark:

Get e from your click handler then try e.preventDefault(); before the return false.